# Migrating SQL Server 2012 Web Edition to Azure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database, sql-server-express

I am trying to migrate to Azure I have gone through this article [Migrate SQL Server to a single database or pooled database in Azure SQL Database online using DMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-azure-sql-online), However since I am having SQL Server Web Edition I wasn't able to configure distribution on premises server I am getting this error related to MSSQL 'web edition'

> In attempting to create the publication, I get This edition of SQL
>   Server cannot act as a Publisher or Distributor for replication.,
>   which is expected as my server is Web edition.

Noting that the article doesn't say the web edition is not supported. So I assume either the article is wrong or there is something else I am missing. I would appreciate if someone has a solution for this issue (on web edition) online migration

Comment: Welcome to DBA stack exchange, would you please provide us with more details.

Comment: The article has an error stating that `any edition` can be used. Web Edition for SQL Server [does not support transnational replication to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017#Replication). You can submit an issue at the bottom of that article to bring it to the team's attention and they can update the article.

Comment: Why not backup the database to Azure Blob storage and then use [this link](https://rajeevpentyala.com/2018/08/24/step-by-step-restore-a-database-from-azure-blob-to-azure-sql-server/) to restore.

Comment: Hi Shawn the article is wrong .. the Web Edition doesn't support duplication ..